# MysqlException was unhandled DataReader with this connection must be closed vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datareader

I have encountered this problem:

**ERROR:** There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.

Please have a look on my code:

```
 Dim sqlQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM users"
    Dim myAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter

    If txtUsername.Text = String.Empty And txtPassword.Text = String.Empty Then
        MsgBox("Enter username and password", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Tea Sparkle POS")
    Else
        Dim sqlquerry = "Select * From users where username = '" + txtUsername.Text + "' And password= '" + txtPassword.Text + "'"
        Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand()
        myCommand.Connection = SQLConnection
        myCommand.CommandText = sqlquerry
        'Starting The Query
        myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand
        Dim mydata As MySqlDataReader
        mydata = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
        'To check the Username and password and to validate the login a
        If mydata.HasRows = 0 Then
            MsgBox("Invalid Login")
            txtPassword.Clear()
            txtUsername.Clear()
        Else
            Dim authorityid = 0
            While mydata.Read()
                authorityid = mydata.GetInt32("authorityid")
            End While
            MsgBox("Welcome " + txtUsername.Text + "!")
            If authorityid = 1 Then
                MainForm.Show()
            Else
                MainForm.Show()
            End If
            Me.Hide()
        End If
    End If


    Private Sub Login_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    SQLConnection.ConnectionString = ServerString

    Try
        If SQLConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            SQLConnection.Open()
        Else
            SQLConnection.Close()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try

End Sub
```

This error is in this line:

```
 mydata = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
```

What's wrong with this? Any help is truly appreciated.

Comment: You need to use a `try/catch` block and post the `exception` message.

Comment: @Brian I've updated my code. I forgot to put what's inside my Form Load

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What's wrong with this?

Well, it looks like you're reusing an existing connection:

```
myCommand.Connection = SQLConnection
```

Don't do that. Create a new connection each time you need to talk to the database, and close it when you've finished, using a `Using` statement to make sure it gets closed even if an exception is thrown.

Additionally, use a `Using` statement for your command, and another for your reader - these are all resources you should be closing.

Oh, and it also looks like you're doing this in the UI thread, which is a bad idea as your UI will be unresponsive while the database access is ongoing.

Comment: Hello, can you give me some examples on who to use Using statement? Thanks.

Comment: `using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand()){ }` is what Jon is talking about.

Comment: @Brian I think this is for c#?

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes - that example is C#, yes.  VB.NET looks like this:  `Using stream As New MemoryStream(buffer, False)`.  Of course, you won't be using a `MemoryStream` in your case.

Comment: @Brian okay thanks. One last thing, can you provide me a good tutorial link on how to use using statement? thank you.

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes: Did you search for "using statement c# msdn" (or the equivalent for VB)?