# Execute multiple stored procedures in VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net, stored-procedures

I'm creating a WinService in VB.NET to get some data from a Table, do some things with these data and then upload new data into this Table.
What I need is something like this:

```vb
Dim conn As New MySqlConnection(my_connString)
conn.Open()

Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("my_Stored_Procedure_1", conn)
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

While reader.Read()
    Try
        ' SP to SELECT Data from DB table '
        Dim columnData As String
        columnData = reader("ColumnName")
        columnData_2 = reader("ColumnName_2")

        ' (...) Do something with this Data '

        Try
            ' SP to UPDATE Data into the same DB table '
            'cmd.Dispose() '
            cmd = New MySqlCommand("my_Stored_Procedure_2", conn)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.ExecuteReader()

            ' (...) Do something else '

        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " & ex.Message)
        End Try
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End While

reader.Close()
conn.Close()
```

The problem is that this doesn't work. It says *There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.* So I tried to create different SQL commands, close and re-open the connection, and create different connections like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14715319/mysqlexception-was-unhandled-datareader-with-this-connection-must-be-closed-vb-n) but all of them without success. [This](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/vmsanthosh.chn/209062007040459AM/2.aspx?ArticleID=96a34245-427e-4e57-adb0-f75ce28d5b1d) class seems to be useful but that's a lot of code for a simple (?) task. I've read a lot of similar questions but I didn't found what I need yet.

How can I handle this issue? Some help would be nice.

Comment: Did you consider making a separate identifier for the command in the loop? And you are not assigning the inner command object's reader to anything.

Comment: those DB Objects not being disposed of like they should be.  the outer portion has an open reader you are iterating which is assopciated with **the** command object.  Inside the While loop you try to use reuse the *same* command object with a stored procedure and whatever happens in *Do something else*.  Dont try and use the same command object simultaneously for multiple tasks

Comment: I tried to use `cmd.Dispose()` or create different command objects but I couldn't get this working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MysqlException was unhandled DataReader with this connection must be closed vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14715319/mysqlexception-was-unhandled-datareader-with-this-connection-must-be-closed-vb-n)

Answer (score 1):

This sure looks like a duplicate of [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14715319/mysqlexception-was-unhandled-datareader-with-this-connection-must-be-closed-vb-n) you linked to, but the answer there doesn't provide a lot of detail on how to fix the error.  As the error says, you can only have one open reader per connection, so you need to use a different connection for the update.  You say you have tried that, but perhaps your attempt was incorrect.  As suggested in the linked question, you should also use `Using` statements for resource management.

So, you probably want something like this (untested, of course!):

```vb
Try
    Using conn1 As New MySqlConnection(my_connString),
          conn2 As New MySqlConnection(my_connString)

        conn1.Open()
        conn2.Open()

        Using cmd1 As New MySqlCommand("my_Stored_Procedure_1", conn1)
            cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

            Using reader1 As MySqlDataReader = cmd1.ExecuteReader()
                While reader1.Read()
                    ' SP to SELECT Data from DB table '
                    Dim columnData As String
                    columnData = reader1("ColumnName")
                    columnData_2 = reader1("ColumnName_2")

                    ' (...) Do something with this Data '

                    ' SP to UPDATE Data into the same DB table '
                    Using cmd2 As New MySqlCommand("my_Stored_Procedure_2", conn2)
                        cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                        Using reader2 As MySqlDataReader = cmd2.ExecuteReader()
                            ' (...) Do something else '
                        End Using ' reader2
                    End Using ' cmd2
                End While
            End Using ' reader1
        End Using ' cmd1
    End Using ' conn1, conn2
Catch ex As Exception
    Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " & ex.Message)
End Try
```

As you can see from the levels of nesting, there is quite a lot going on here in terms of the resource scopes, so you may want to refactor this into multiple methods.  You could also use a data adapter to populate a `DataTable` for the results of `my_Stored_Procedure_1`, instead of using a `DataReader`, and then just need a single connection (assuming the data isn't too large for that).